# Inserting data in table at the time of database creation using FMDB in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using FMDB to create local database in iOS. I want some predefined data to be inserted when the app is installed or at the time of database creation.

One way to achieve this is that I should check whether data is already inserted or not by executing a `Select` query in `AppDelegate` and checking count of data. But I guess there should be a better way. Something like `onCreate()` method of database in Android which is called only once when a database is created. Can anyone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Since you already have a way to achieve what you need, I think try should tell how different you expect the answers to be.

Comment: @GwendalRoué What I mean is that is there any method/callback to check database is created or not and calls only once? Same like onCreate() method of database in Android.